# Spring Data JDBC not using join when requesting related tables

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

I have 2 linked tables in the same aggregate but *Spring Data JDBC* does not use join for retrieving data. It does several Select requests instead, and I don't see why.

The tables:

```
TestA (aggregate root)
    idA (integer, PK)
```

```
TestB
    idB (integer, PK)
    idA (integer, FK -> TestA)
```

Entities:

```java
@Data
public class TestA {
    @Id
    Integer idA;
    
    @MappedCollection(idColumn = "idA")
    Set<TestB> testBs = new HashSet<>();
}
```

```java
@Data
public class TestB {
    @Id
    Integer idB;
}
```

Repository:

```java
@Repository
public interface TestRepository extends CrudRepository<TestA, Integer> {
}
```

When calling **testRepository.findAll()**, it retrieves all the data and the objects are as expected (I have all the TestA with a list of associated TestB for each one), but it does it by requesting data from TestA, and then for each TestA line it requests TestB.

```
Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT TestA.idA AS idA FROM TestA]
Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT TestB.idB AS idB FROM TestB WHERE TestB.idA = ?]
Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT TestB.idB AS idB FROM TestB WHERE TestB.idA = ?]
...
```

Why not a single **Select with JOIN??** I guess I'm doing something wrong that is probably obvious, but I don't get it. For me and from my understanding it should be a left join or something like that, to retrieve in a single request data from TestA with the associated data from TestB.

Answer (score 1):

No you are not doing anything wrong.
This is just how Spring Data JDBC works right now.

The team is working on a new more efficient way to load aggregates, but it isn't ready yet.

If this is a problem for you you can specify your own query including a dedicated `RowMapper` or `ResultSetExtractor` in a `@Query` annotation.

Comment: Could you make an example how to use `ResultSetExtractor` in a `@Query` annotation or point to the documentation where it explains how to do it?