# Spring Data JDBC read optimization

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

I am just starting out with Spring Data JDBC. In my test project I now have a request that is very slow in the result, because a lot of queries are sent to the database.

Here is an extract to illustrate the principle of my problem. There will be several thousand data records in the real database.

There is a model with articles and prices in a 1:n relation. This results in this example data model:

```java
@Table("articles")
public class ArticleModel {

    @Id
    @Column("id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column("name")
    private String name;

    @Column("size")
    private String size;

    @MappedCollection(idColumn = "article_id", keyColumn = "id")
    private Set<ArticlePriceModel> prices;
   //getter setter
}
```

```java
@Table("article_prices")
public class ArticlePriceModel {
    @Id
    @Column("id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column("type_id")
    private String priceType;

    @Column("price")
    private BigDecimal price;

    @Column("article_id")
    AggregateReference<ArticleModel, Integer> articleReference;
    //getter setter
```

I use this repository for queries:

```java
public interface ArticleRepository extends CrudRepository<ArticleModel, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE name LIKE :name")
    List<ArticleModel> findByName(String name);

    @Query(value =  """
            SELECT a.*, ap.* FROM articles a
                INNER JOIN article_prices ap ON a.id = ap.article_id
                WHERE type_id LIKE 'retail' AND name LIKE :name
            """
            , rowMapperClass = SinglePriceRowMapper.class)
    List<ArticleModel> findByNameWithRetailPrice(String name);
}
```

This means that with `findByName`, a further SELECT is executed for each result row (==ArticleModel) to determine the prices. However, the data could also be collected all together directly using a JOIN. In the current implementation it is very slow for a large resultset.
Here is the first question: Is there a way for Spring Data JDBC to create the data structure directly from a join with just one select command?

The special feature of my second select `findByNameWithRetailPrice` is that you can create the structure completely with one line in the resulset.
Is there a way to do this automatically?

As I haven't found anything for this so far, I have created my own implementation with the RowMapper.

```java
public class SinglePriceRowMapper implements RowMapper<ArticleModel> {

    @Override
    public ArticleModel mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        ArticleModel result = new ArticleModel();

        result.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
        result.setName(rs.getString("name"));
        result.setSize(rs.getString("size"));

        ArticlePriceModel price = new ArticlePriceModel();
        price.setId(rs.getInt(findIndex(rs, "article_prices", "id")));
        price.setPrice(rs.getBigDecimal("price"));
        price.setPriceType(rs.getString("type_id"));

        result.setPrices(Set.of(price));

        return result;
    }
```

However, my problem is that I have to write a lot of code that also contains the column names hard-coded in the source code. The `@Column` annotations of the models are not accessed. Is there any way to simplify this so that you don't have to build the RowMapper 100% yourself? It would be practical if you could use a basic RowMapper here and onlIt would be practical if you could use a basic RowMapper here and then implement your own additional mappings. RowMapper is an interface and I haven't seen any implementations that you could simply overwrite.

I have created a small test project which can be found here: https://github.com/Malte-Neu/spring-data-jdbc-test

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Data JDBC not using join when requesting related tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73475396/spring-data-jdbc-not-using-join-when-requesting-related-tables)

Comment: It seems that there is experimental support for loading aggregates in the latest version 3.2 https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/relational/reference/jdbc/entity-persistence.html#:~:text=for%20further%20details.-,Loading%20Aggregates,query%20or%20a%20annotated%20query. but for your use-case you might want to consider using standard JPA (using Spring Data JPA) which does this out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for the links @jbx: I had also found the referred question, so I implemented it with the RowMapper, which has some disadvantages as written.
The feature in 3.2 does not solve my problem either, as I use a list. OpenJpa may be better for this case, but it doesn't fulfill my other requirements. Furthermore, I don't want to maintain two model structures and tools.

Comment: what other requirements does Spring Data JPA not fulfill? If you just replace MappedCollection with OneToMany it does exactly what you need.

Comment: I wanted to do without JPA completely. In another project, I didn't have good experiences with all the magic and caching. That's why I wanted to get "closer" to the jdbc.

Comment: Ok, well every tool needs good understanding if you want to use it correctly. Unfortunately it seems that what you want is what JPA was designed to do. The other solutions are more rudimentary and will require that you code the mappers and infrastructure to handle relationships.

Comment: The question here is only an excerpt from a special optimization problem. Spring jdbc works for the other parts. I am already happy if there is a way that I don't have to write the mapper completely myself, instead I can modify or extend an existing one to achieve my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The experimental feature of [Single Query Loading](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/relational/reference/jdbc/entity-persistence.html#jdbc.loading-aggregates) should solve your problem.

Note that it doesn't support *nested* collections. A single level of collection as you have in your model shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Based on the documentation ("It only works for the find methods in CrudRepository, not for derived queries and not for annotated queries."), it doesn't work for my case as I am creating a custom query. But maybe in the future.